# The full counterpart of 'night' in Russian

Tags: перевод, одним-словом

So, I've stumbled upon an interesting question and, being a native speaker of Russian, I don't know the accurate answer.

In English, there exists a word *night*. It means the period from sunset to sunrise. However, I don't know a full counterpart in Russian that would express the same thing. I know that вечер means the period from sunset to bedtime, and ночь means the period from bedtime to sunrise. Is there a short word or a common phrase that would be able to combine both meanings?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128672/discussion-on-question-by-rusurano-the-full-counterpart-of-night-in-russian).

Comment: Let's be civil. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the name of period from sunset to sunrise is ночь (night).

[https://gufo.me/dict/ozhegov/ночь](https://gufo.me/dict/ozhegov/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%8C)

"тёмное время суток" is just a bureaucratesed "ночь". The question is just inadequate.

"I know that вечер means the period from sunset to bedtime," - no, which "beditme" here...

"be able to combine both meanings?" - which "both meanings" ? :> If it's about evening+night - we haven't a special word for this period, but you could say : "время, когда стемнеет", and it's not accurate because вечер isn't certainly dark only...

Comment: "we haven't a special word for this period" - this is the answer.

Comment: I think what the OP is getting at is the at the period from about 
6 or 7PM to midnight when dinners and theatrical performances are held is frequently called "night", as in "tonight's performance", but it is not "ночь".

Comment: David42 All these isn't a night, and so - not important who or how not accurately and drunked colloquially call this as "night". In Russian this aren't using, in the main.
Or as metaphor...

Answer (score 1):

I guess we haven't that one, if you want to name period from sunset to sunrise you can say *"тёмное время суток"*.

Comment: Your translation is actually a very good one, but only for particular cases. For instance, it won't fit for casual conversations, for example «‎‎встретимся в тёмное время суток». It has this 'official' flavor to it. I guess this answer should be extended by more contextual cases.

Comment: I guess вечер also has meaning of period from sunset to sunrise but it depends on context

Comment: This topic has been discussed here a few times. See: [Telling time in Russian: when does night, morning, afternoon, and evening start?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/12611/telling-time-in-russian-when-does-night-morning-afternoon-and-evening-start), [How long is the night from the Russian language standpoint?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/20486/how-long-is-the-night-from-the-russian-language-standpoint/20487#20487).

Comment: "тёмное время суток" is just the bureaucratesed "ночь". the question is just inadequate.